# How to initialize the camera for players in Photon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I making 2D game, the problem is that when the first player creates and appears in the room his camera is working normally, but when a new player enters the room, the first player sees everything through the camera of the second player. Further, if a third player connects, the first and second players see everything through the third player’s camera and so on.

Player prefab instantiated in the GameManager class which is only on the game scene

```cs
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
    {
        public GameObject playerPrefab;
        public Transform spawnPoint;

        public void Start()
        {
            GameObject player = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(this.playerPrefab.name, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
            player.GetComponent<FireFighterHeroController>().enabled = true;
            player.GetComponent<CameraControler>().enabled = true;
            player.GetComponent<CameraControler>().SetTarget(player.transform);
        }

        #region PUN Callbacks

        public override void OnLeftRoom()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Custom Methods

        public void OnClickLeaveRoom_Btn()
        {
            PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom();
        }

        #endregion
}
```

Simple camera controller

```cs
public class CameraControler : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Transform target;
        public GameObject camera;
        public Vector3 offset;

        public void SetTarget(Transform target)
        {
            this.target = target;
        }

        public void LateUpdate()
        {
            camera.transform.position = target.position + offset;
        }
    }
```

**UPD Found a solution**

I moved the script of the camera controller to the player’s camera, and in the player’s instance I search for this camera, turn it on and transfer the player’s transform to it.

Not sure about this method, but it at least works.

Here is that monster

```cs
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
    {
        public Transform spawnPoint;

        public void Start()
        {
            GameObject player = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Player", spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);

            if (!player.GetPhotonView().IsMine)
                return;
            player.GetComponent<FireFighterHeroController>().enabled = true;
            player.transform.Find("Camera").gameObject.GetComponent<CameraControler>().enabled = true;
            player.transform.Find("Camera").gameObject.GetComponent<CameraControler>().SetTarget(player.transform);
            player.transform.Find("Camera").gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
}
```

And Camera Controller

```cs
public class CameraControler : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Transform target;
        public Vector3 offset;

        public void SetTarget(Transform target)
        {
            this.target = target;
        }

        public void LateUpdate()
        {
            gameObject.transform.position = target.position + offset;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE - AFTER YOUR COMMENT**
You're sending the commands to all players.

Before sending the command you should check if the player receiving the command is OWNER of the new player.

Basically you're doing this.

=> CREATE PLAYER
=> ASSIGN CAMERA

When you should to this.

=> CREATE PLAYER
=> CHECK IF THIS YOUR CLIENT => ASSIGN CAMERA

To achieve that you need to add this check:

```
if (photonView.IsMine) AssignCamera();
```

I see that you're sending the command in the manager. So you have these solutions:

- Add in the manager a way to check if this is the player
- (Better) move the code inside player script.

### ADD CODE INSIDE PLAYER SCRIPT

```cs
public class YourPlayer : Photon.MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        //stop assigning controls if this is not the player related to this peer
        if(!photonView.IsMine) return;
        player.GetComponent<FireFighterHeroController>().enabled = true;
        player.GetComponent<CameraControler>().enabled = true;
        player.GetComponent<CameraControler>().SetTarget(player.transform);
    }
}
```

### **ADD THE CHECK IN THE MANAGER**

I'm not sure about all the logic of your code. Some code should apply to all players, some other code should apply only to Peer Related player.

I think you should just change the Start method like so:

```
public void Start()
{
    GameObject player = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(this.playerPrefab.name, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);

    //stop assigning controls if this is not the player related to this peer
    if(!player.GetPhotonView().IsMine) return;
    player.GetComponent<FireFighterHeroController>().enabled = true;
    player.GetComponent<CameraControler>().enabled = true;
    player.GetComponent<CameraControler>().SetTarget(player.transform);
}
```

Further info: [Player Networking - Photon PUN](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/demos-and-tutorials/pun-basics-tutorial/player-networking)

Comment: Hi, yes, I read the documentation and tried this method before asking a question here. This does not work because GameManager is a separate object on scene and it does not have PhotonView components. The PhotonView component is located only at the player’s prefab. I also tried this method with this component in Game Manager, but it still does not work correctly. Anyway, thanks for the help, I will trying to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried with `player.GetPhotonView().IsMine`? You can also just move the 3 lines related to the camera controller inside your player monobehaviour to achieve just the same result. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, your advice prompted me to how solve this problem, I updated the post